# One to Many Update Realm Android Issue

Tags: android, realm, relational-database

I have been updating my realm database like below. and it worked fine.

```
Orders tempOrder = realm.where(Orders.class).equalTo("orderId", orderId).findFirst();
                tempOrder.setImage1(imagePath1);
                tempOrder.setImage2(imagePath2);
                tempOrder.setImageFailed(isImageFailed);
                tempOrder.setImageComment(imageComment);
```

and now i wanted to update its relation table. and i did like below after above code.

```
                RealmList<Products>tempProducts = tempOrder.getProducts();
                for(int i=0;i<tempProducts.size();i++){
                   tempProducts.get(i).setQAChecked(tempProducts.get(i).getSelected());
                }
                tempOrder.setProducts(tempProducts);

                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(tempOrder);
```

but after updating database my products become empty. can any one guide me what im doing wrong here.

Comment: begin and end transation?

Comment: i tried it didnt work. anyway i found another solution. im updating Products and Order Tables individually